# Can a class instance created by another class instance access the creator's members?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an instance of a Python class that is creating another, and I'm wondering if the "created" class can access members of the "creator" without passing them in explicitly, or doing something like this:

```
class Creator(object):
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.parameter = parameter
        self.created = Created(self)

class Created(object):
    def __init__(self, creator):
        self.creator = creator
        self.parameter = self.creator.parameter
```

I guess what I'm trying to do is allow `parameter` to be accessed by both, except in practice there will be multiple parameters, so passing them all will result in a long list of arguments. My solution right now is to use a `Creator` as an argument to a `Created`. Is there a less awkward or smarter way to do this? Maybe put all the parameters in a dictionary?

Comment: As a side note, `class Creator():` is an old-style class rather than new-style, which you almost never want. (And on the rare occasions when you do, you should write it as `class Creator:`.) Always do `class Creator(object):` to create a new-style class instead.

Comment: The awkward feeling hints that the creator/created referencing may not be the better pattern to solve your problem. A more concrete example could help to get a better answer, for example, is it for gaming?

Comment: Do you really need Creator to be a class? I think in your case, a simple factory function would work just as fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, and you've almost done it, with one minor problem:

```
class Created():
    def __init__(self, creator):
        self.parameter = self.creator.parameter
```

There is no `self.creator`. If you never need to access it again after this `__init__` call, just use the `creator` parameter directly:

```
class Created():
    def __init__(self, creator):
        self.parameter = creator.parameter
```

If you need it later, store it as `self.creator`, and then of course you can access it there:

```
class Created():
    def __init__(self, creator):
        self.creator = creator
        self.parameter = self.creator.parameter
```

… although you probably don't even need to copy over `parameter` in that case, because you can always get to it as `self.creator.parameter`.

This is a very common pattern.

The only real downside to this is that if you keep the back-reference around (`self.creator = creator`), you can't have any `__del__` methods. (Or you need to make it a `weakref`, or an indirect reference, like a key that can be used to look up the creator as needed.)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it looks fine. If parameter is a class attribute instead of instance, you can use inheritance, but I don't think it is such an improvement.

```
def creator_factory(param):
    class Creator(object):
        parameter = param
    return Creator

Creator = creator_factory(something)

class Created(Creator):
    pass

>>> Created().parameter
'something'
```

Comment: Turning an instance attribute into a class attribute, and making a class inherit from an unrelated class, just so you can avoid passing a `self` one time?

Comment: You are right, there is no point doing this if classes are unrelated, but Creator and Created sharing the same attribute hints at hierarchy (the example provided by the OP is too abstract to know for sure).

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
class Creator():
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.parameter = parameter
        self.created = Created()
        self.created.creator = self
```